# How to make a while with else in it

Tags: excel, vba, loops, while-loop, repeat

so i have this piece of code here:

```
While day = "M"
            Call Schedule(i)
        Wend
        While day = "T"
            Call Schedule(i)
        Wend
        While day = "W"
            Call Schedule(i)
        Wend
        While day = "R"
            Call Schedule(i)
        Wend
        While day = "F"
            Call Schedule(i)
        Wend
```

is there a simpler way to write all these while statements. to clarify things, i a have a sheet that has like 2000 lines with info about courses and i want the code to read the days in order of the wekk : Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri so how can i do that here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need 5 loops independent of each other.  One for each day in the order you want.

Comment: There really isn't enough code here to see what you're doing (where is `day` being set?)- I suspect that the easiest thing to do would be a custom sort.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do multiple cases is using [`Select Case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)

```
Select Case day
    Case "M"
        Schedule(i)
    Case "T"
        Schedule(i)
    Case "W"
        Schedule(i)
    Case "R"
        Schedule(i)
    Case "F"
        Schedule(i)
End Select
```

Comment: i had the cases before but as i said i need the days to be in order, i literally had that snippet before its just that shows everything unordered/not the way i want it

Comment: @GhaithHaddad You will need to share more of your worksheet and what you are trying to do with the data.  Your question as it stands is unclear.  As of right now, all you have asked is a easier way to write your existing code.

Comment: @Charismas007 I honestly dont think that you guys need any of the other code cuz everything is set and was working perfectly  its just that my boss told me to find a way that allow the code to read the days in order and call the Schedule module to do its thing. like lets say that the worksheet had rows with days like this:
monday
wednesday
tuesday
friday 
monday
thusday
friday

and what i want is that it first reads all the mondays, then goes to tuesdays, and so on so forth

Comment: and when it finds a monday lets say it will then call the Schedule module to do its thing, hope that helps calrify things up. Thnx